# How to check if 2 objects that contains list as a data member equal or not?

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, equals

I am having 2 entities namely `Project` and `File` in SpringBoot. The structure of those entity is as given below.

```
@Document(collection="project")
public class Project{
    
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    @Field("files")
    @DBRef
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<File> files;
}

@Document(collection="file")
public class File{
    
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    @Field("project")
    @DBRef
    private Project project;
}
```

Now when I am creating an object of `Project` entity, saving it in database and fetching it again from the database using the Repository and trying to use `equals` method it is returning `false`.
When I checked individually for each attribute it was failing for the `List<File> files` which is present in the `Project`. But it is understandable that it will fail because the `equals` method of `File` class will only return `true` if each of it's data member will satisfy `equals` but as the `File` have a reference to `Project`, it will fail.
So this is kind of creating a loop.

If I override the `equals` method of `Project` to as given below, it works, but at the cost of neglecting the `List<File> file`.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(!(obj instanceof Project))
            return false;
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        Project that = (Project) obj;
        return
            this.id.equals(that.id) &&
                this.name.equals(that.name);
    }
```

How to solve this problem taking into consideration of the list of files as well?

Comment: Try overriding the equals and hashcode method.  Include all the properties that you need to chd k for equality in equals as well as has ode method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you could revisit your design.
Often developers create circular dependencies with Entities(or Documents) when it is not required.

I assume your business case is one of the below:

> A) Files are always associated to a Project (there are no files
> without a project association)
>
> B) All Projects contain atleast one File (there are no projects
> without atleast one file)
>
> C) There can be projects without files or files without a project
> associated to it.

**For case C ONLY:**
You should be prefering a circular dependency and that too ONLY if business needs it.

**For case A and case B:**
You have an aggregate here, a project with a list of files associated with it, (or files with project).

> "Aggregate" is a pattern in Domain Driven Design, where these two
> objects essentially can be treated as a single unit.

Also, when we think in that perspective, there needs to be just one repo as well for these Documents (aggregate).

You can check out this talk from Pivotal for more on aggregates : [Talk on Aggregate and Spring Data JPA, from Pivotal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnIouYdwxo0&ab_channel=SpringDeveloper)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the equals method and, check for equality of list just by matching the id's of the list objects in a different method. Or maybe you can use containsAll() to check for list elements equality. This is not a perfect solution but still checks for the list elements instead of completely ignoring them.

Also checkout circular dependency here and try to structure those entities in a different way:

https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: I am not getting any of the exception that is mentioned in the blog that you suggested. And actually I'll need it to be circular as I should be able to go back and forth i.e., from projects I should be able to fetch the list of the files that are there and from file I should be able to determine which project that file belongs to. I thought of containsAll() but it'll increase the conplexity to O(n^2). Is there anyway else I could achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save just Project.id in File. I'm assuming you need that just for reference. Compare the usecase, how often you'll need to find project from file or file from project and accordingly save.

Comment: Right now I am saving the entire object of project and just checking their ids, but what if we want to solve this? Is there any way?